# ASP.NET OWIN - Adding WsFederation at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs, ws-federation

I'd like to add support for administrators to add a trusted federation to my site. I'm trying to do this in my controller without having to restart the web app using:

```
app.Map("/Account", configuration =>
{
    var provider = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = organizationModel.ADFS_Domain,
        MetadataAddress = organizationModel.ADFS_MetadataAddress,
        BackchannelCertificateValidator = null,
        Wtrealm = organizationModel.ADFS_Realm,
        Wreply = serveraddress + " /Account/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    };

     configuration.UseWsFederationAuthentication(provider);

});
```

The code above executes without errors, but the provider is not added to the Owin context. Calling...

```
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes()
```

does not include the new option... :(

Just to clarify, I can do the same thing in my Startup.Auth.cs, but again, I don't want to restart the host...

Any ideas?